# PMF for a multiple choice quiz

Tags: probability

A student takes a multiple choice test of $20$ questions where each
question has $5$ possible options for the answers. Suppose the student answers each question
at random. Let $R$ be the random variable denoting the number of correct answers, and
let the pass mark for the test be $8$ or more correct answers.

(a) Give the pmf of $R$.
(b) Work out $P(R = 0), P(R = 1), P(R = 20).$
(c) Find numerically the probability that the student fails the test

Many thanks.

Comment: I think that (a) is p(R)= 1/5 for r=1,2,3,4,5.

Comment: Think about what needs to happen to have $i$ answers correct. For example, to have two correct answers, you need to answer exactly two (does not matter which two) of the twenty questions correctly and the remaining eighteen incorrectly. How many ways can you answer two answers correctly out of twenty questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Learn about the binomial distribution.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints**
First choose the $R$ questions the student has answered correctly from $20$
Then find the probability that *all* of those $R$ questions are answered correctly
Then find the probability that *all* of the remaining questions are answered false.

Comment: So it is a binomial distribution $R~Bin(20,1/5)$   ?? Thanks

Comment: @PureMaths Yes, $R\sim \mathop{\rm Bin}(20, \frac15)$.